# timestamp with offset +05:30 need to be converted into yyyy mm dd hh mm ss format using mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, datetime

using mongo aggr i need to convert an epoch to human-readable date eg my epoch :1563557673 which i want in yyyy mm dd hr mm ss and offset +05:30`

```
displayTime: moment(getReferral[0][i].timeStamp * 1000)
                        .utcOffset("+05:30")
                        .format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A")
```

Comment: i have used below aggr so far to and reached here "date": ISODate("2019-07-19T17:34:33Z"), but i need +05:30 zone as well ass i dont need T and Z .

/code ---------db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "date": {
        "$toDate": {
          $multiply: [
            "$_id",
            1000
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Comment: Use [$dateToString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

Comment: `new Date(1563557673*1e3).toLocaleString('en-CA',{timeZone:'Asia/Kolkata'})` is pretty close. ;-)